# Logitech webcam V-UT21

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 OS and cheese but it cannot see or open Logitech web-cam Quick cam V-UT21 plug and play which I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing luvcview.  It somestimes works when cheese doesn't.
In a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t)

```
sudo apt-get install luvcview
```